# Why does nchar("\\")=1 in R?

Tags: regex, string, r, character

Why does `nchar("\\")=1, nchar("\abcde")=5` etc. in R ? Which function use to have `nchar("\\")=2, nchar("\abcde")=6` ?

Comment: At a guess, ``\`` is an escape character in R strings. So ``\\`` is interpreted as a single ``\``.

Comment: \u2642 is a unicode characrter at my best guess

Comment: It might have something to do with the different options of nchar()? As you can read [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/nchar.html), there are some special cases with NA, UTF-8 etc. Maybe it's running in some kind of "fallback" for "\\"?

Comment: what's wrong with my question ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In R, if you want a literal `\`, you need to escape it as other's have said. I don't see the reason for `encodeString()` in your examples. It is easier to just use `nchar()` and remember the first line of my Answer: **escape your `\`**

```
> nchar("\\\\")
[1] 2
> nchar("\\abcde")
[1] 6
```

If you want to forget about the escape then `encodeString()` can help, but you either do one (escape them manually) *or* use `escapeString()`, not both:

```
> encodeString("\\")
[1] "\\\\"
> encodeString("\abcde")
[1] "\\abcde"
```

Finally, `\uXXXX` is a way of entering a unicode characters in R and this catches out `encodeString()`:

```
> nchar(encodeString("\u2642"))
[1] 1
```

as it wants to treat this as a representation of a unicode character. In this case, the "escape them yourself" thing does the right thing:

```
> nchar("\\u2642")
[1] 6
```

I'm not sure of a straight forward way to replace `\` with `\\` in R where the string is a `\uXXXX` as that will get interpreted first to the unicdoe character and only then will the replacement take place (but at that point there are no `\`. See `?Quotes` for a list of the escape sequences used in R.

Answer (score 4):

The backslash is [escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) the next character.
This is common in many programming languages; lets you embed control and other non-printing characters in your string, like `\n' to mean newline.

So '\' is really the single `\` character.
The simplest way to address your concern is to double the backslashes: `nchar("\\abcde") = 6`.

Comment: @Qbik, From `?encodeString`: "This escapes backslash and the control characters", so you're really doing `nchar(\\\\abcde")`, which is 7

Comment: @BenBarnes yes but it works : `nchar(encodeString("abcde"))=5 nchar(encodeString("\abcde"))=6`

Comment: @Qbik stop using `encodeString()`; hat is the problem with the `\uXXXX` ones as R parses that to a unicode character and at that point there isn't much you can do. Manual escaping works fine. See my Answer

Answer (score 1):

> `nchar(encodeString("\\"))`

should give you what you want.

Comment: but nchar("\\abced", type = "bytes")=6 not 7,encodeString is more useful